# What are the advantages of LLDB over GDB in iOS development?

Tags: ios, debugging, gdb, lldb

In Xcode 4.3, now you can enable using LLDB as the debugger for iOS targets.

[image]

What advantages does it have over using the good old GDB? GDB still works with LLVM and I cannot see any obvious differences in "everyday" debugging tasks.

Comment: Yeah, I hoped there would be answers less obvious then mine too. Looks like all the wonderful LLDB features are under the hood.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most notable advantage is that LLDB understands dot syntax in properties:

```
po self.property
```

A quote from [LLVM project blog](http://blog.llvm.org/2010/06/new-lldb-debugger.html):

> LLDB supports basic command line debugging scenarios on the Mac, is scriptable, and has great support for multithreaded debugging. LLDB is already much faster than GDB when debugging large programs, and has the promise to provide a much better user experience (particularly for C++ programmers). We are excited to see the new platforms, new features, and enhancements that the broader LLVM community is interested in.

Another quote from [LLDB homepage](http://lldb.llvm.org/):

> LLDB is a next generation, high-performance debugger. It is built as a set of reusable components which highly leverage existing libraries in the larger LLVM Project, such as the Clang expression parser and LLVM disassembler.
>
> *Why a new debugger*
>   In order to achieve our goals we decided to start with a fresh architecture that would support modern multi-threaded programs, handle debugging symbols in an efficient manner, use compiler based code knowledge and have plug-in support for functionality and extensions. Additionally we want the debugger capabilities to be available to other analysis tools, be they scripts or compiled programs, without requiring them to be GPL.

Comment: lldb still has a long way to go for simpler command typing.  It still takes very strong typing to get the same result as gdb, plus no auto-completion at command line.